# delay processing in java application

Tags: java, file

Can someone please help me out.  I have an application that creates a file to be processed by an external application.  I need to somehow delay my code to wait until there is a file created from the external application.  But I am having issues finding anything that cause a delay in the Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple, but, crude: `File.isFile()` and `Thread.sleep()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty rudimentary and crude but technically, `Thread.sleep()` induces delay.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, simple, but crude:

```
File f = new File("your-file.txt");

for (;;)
{
    try
    {
        if (f.isFile())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Or some other appropriate
        // handling of the exception.
    }

    try
    {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage users to write empty catch blocks. Print the stack trace, log something, at least put a comment explaining why it's empty but just don't leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
while(!file.exists());
```

Answer (score 0):

> delay my code to wait until there is a file created

It is better to activate methods in your code when something happens.  To do that I would suggest a *separate* `Thread` that runs and checks the condition, then calls your apps. method if needed. For an app. with a GUI, this would typically be achieved using a Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), but I believe it can also be achieved using a [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling for a file change with a timer, you could just use the Java file API and wait for a file modification event. Here are the docs: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

and here is a small example:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java